# emulator not displaying web content properly

Tags: android, url, webview, svg, android-webview

I'm using webview to display content from certain URL.

Check 2nd and 3rd links by *opening separately* in your computer browser from here

[2nd link](http://www.amcharts.com/)
and
[3rd link](http://ipad.idealake.com/stockcharts.aspx?id=Reliance)
.

2nd and 3rd links works fine in computer browser but when I try to load them in webView, it is not getting properly displayed.

in 2nd link, link is getting opened, but charts are not getting displayed while in 3rd link nothing is getting displayed at all.

3rd link also contains a chart made using 2nd link.

Is this problem occurring because of any limitation of android emulator?

Note that **I TRIED WITH 4.0 EMULATOR, BUT I GET THE SAME OUTPUT...**

**ANY HELP WILL BE LIFE-SAVER !!!**

**Screen Shot**
[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the links are all using SVG. That is introduced in 3.2 as a quick google shows: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+svg+browser+support&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

This is not supported in 2.2, I would recommend using a simulator version of honeycomb, 3.2 or IceCreamSandwich.

Comment: I would suggest you try to find some svg that works on an andorid phone (that supports svg) then compare the difference. maybe there is a property or type or aspect of svg that is not fully supported?

Comment: I followed http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/wiki/Tutorial and got the output. But it's for `imageview`. I want to show data from URL into a `webView`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One of the common reasons for the web page to appear crumpled in mobile is because they are designed for browser width and height and not mobile versions.Simple example: See the difference in facebook page on browser and on phone. It fits properly because it the mobile version ( m.facebook.com,m.google.com).If you can , then get the mobile version of the webpage.

Comment: in that case, 2nd link shouldn't have opened. But it is opening without displaying the graph content(*see blank boxes in 2nd scrrenshot*).

Comment: Did you check the internet speed,there are occasions it takes time to load images in phone

Comment: more heavier page than my link for instance *apple.com* is getting displayed, but these link doesn't work.